# Should the approach speed and wind be changed below 700ft on an A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, airspeed

The FCOM says:

> - When managed, the speed target is computed by the FMGS and may be
>   modified by the flight crew through the MCDU. At 700 ft RA, the
>   current speed target value is memorized by the autothrust, to ensure
>   stabilized speed guidance, even if Flight Management fails. **Below
>   700 ft, any new VAPP or WIND entry in the MCDU has no effect on the
>   speed target.**
> - When selected, the autothrust always targets the
>   speed selected on the FCU

I saw some captains changes VAPP and wind in MCDU below 700ft. Is this wrong?

Comment: Is the airline SOP explicitly prohibiting it? The FCOM quote doesn't prohibit manual changes, it only explains that the FMGS doesn't change the speed but manual selection on the FCU is valid.